# What constitutes a minimal-sum section of an integer array

Tags: arrays

I'm having trouble understanding what constitutes a "minimal sum section" of an integer array. My book defines it as the following:

> Let $a[0],\dots, a[n-1]$ be the integer values of an array $a$.
>   A *section* of $a$ is a continuous piece $a[i],\dots,a[j]$, where $0\le i \le j < n$. We write $S_i,_j$ for the sum of that section: $a[i] + a[i+1]+\dots+a[j]$.
>   A *minimal-sum section* is a section $a[i],\dots,a[j]$ of $a$ such that the sum $S_{i,j}$ is less than or equal to the sum $S_{i',j'}$ of any other section $a[i'],\dots,a[j']$ of $a$.

My confusion comes with one of the examples that follow this definition:

> The array [1,-1,3,-1,1] has two minimal-sum sections [1,-1] and [-1,1] with minimal sum 0.

But, wouldn't the minimal sum section be $[-1]$ ?

In a later example they give:

> array $[-1,3,-2]$

Minimal sum

> section $[-2]$

So, in the last example they definitely counted one element as the minimal sum section, but not in the first one. Any clarification on why this is so would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If your book is *Huth, M; Ryan, M: "Logic in Computer Science: Modelling and Reasoning about Systems"* (part in question *4.3.3 A case study: minimal-sum section*), I take it to be a simple error on behalf of the authors and lectors in an example intended to show something else: that *minimal-sum section*s do not need to be unique. (9780521543101, no errata found at [Cambridge University Press](https://www.cambridge.org).)

Comment: Looks like a mistake. According to the definition, the minimal sum section in your first example should indeed be $-1$.

Comment: @greybeard yes that's the book.